# Strict stationarity and existence of moments ARCH(1)

Tags: stationarity, garch

Can a **strictly  stationary** time series not have the fourth moment? For example the ARCH(1) process with the a(1) coefficient $ > \frac{1}{3}$ doesn't have the fourth moment. Can it be strictly stationary?

Comment: By *autoregressive coefficient*, do you mean the coefficient in front of the lagged squared error term in the conditional variance equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strictly stationary process is one whose unconditional joint probability distribution does not change when shifted in time. There is no restriction on moments, though. E.g. an i.i.d. sequence of Cauchy random variables is strictly stationary even though the random variable does not have any integer moments.

Regarding the particular case of ARCH(1), Francq & Zakoian ["GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/GARCH+Models%3A+Structure%2C+Statistical+Inference+and+Financial+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781119313489) (2nd edition, 2019) say on p. 22:

> In the ARCH(1) case ($\beta=0$), the strict stationarity constraint is written as
> $$
> 0 \leq \alpha < \exp\{−\mathbb{E}(\log \eta_t^2)\} \tag{2.10}.
> $$
> For instance when $\eta_t\sim N(0,1)$, the condition becomes $\alpha<3.56$. For a distribution such that $\mathbb{E}(\log \eta_t^2)=−\infty$, for instance with a mass at $0$, condition ($2.10$) is always satisfied. For such distributions, a strictly stationary ARCH(1) solution exists whatever the value of $\alpha$.

$\eta$ is the standardized innovation, $\alpha$ is the coefficient in front of the lagged squared error term in the conditional variance equation. So if the standardized innovations are Normal, then $\alpha>\frac{1}{3}$ is fine (the process is strictly stationary) as long as $\alpha<3.56$.